# error: 1111 Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I have searched for solutions but all seem to need to replace WHERE with HAVING. I don't believe this to have the same issue and I am unable to figure out what could be wrong. I have tried replacing different parts of the code where I had references and any aggregate functions in the WHERE clause but I am still left with the same error. The following is my entire MySQL statement which fetches statistics for sellers and their performance for a chosen period.

```
SELECT users.name AS sellername, users.id AS sellerid, `providers`.`id`, providers.name AS providername, 
COUNT(sales.id) as brutto, COUNT(sale_netto.id) as netto, AVG(sale_quality.grade) as grade, 
SUM(COUNT(sales.id)-COUNT(sale_netto.id)) as diff, (COUNT(sales.id)/COUNT(sales.id)+COUNT(sale_netto.id))*100 AS perc 
FROM `product_regretrules` 
LEFT JOIN `product_categories` ON `product_categories`.`id` = `product_regretrules`.`product_category_id` 
LEFT JOIN `product_product_category` ON `product_product_category`.`product_category_id` = `product_categories`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `products` ON `products`.`id` = `product_regretrules`.`product_id` 
OR `products`.`id` = `product_product_category.product_id` 
LEFT JOIN `sales` ON `sales`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `sale_netto` ON `sale_netto`.`sale_id` = `sales`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `sales`.`seller_id` 
LEFT JOIN `providers` ON `providers`.`id` = `products`.`provider_id` 
LEFT JOIN `sale_quality` ON `sale_quality`.`sale_id` = `sales`.`id` 
WHERE `sale_netto`.`upload_id` = 725 
AND `sale_netto`.`id` is not null 
AND `sales`.`sell_date` between 2015-12-04 and 2016-08-06 
AND `product_regretrules`.`deleted_at` is null 
GROUP BY `users.id`, `providers`.`id`
```

Please look at the problem with the query, I am not interested in answers or comments on how to get the right numbers/stats.

Comment: Seems like this part was the cause of the issue 'SUM(COUNT(sales.id)-COUNT(sale_netto.id)) as diff' I would answer but I am not sure why it caused the issue so I am hoping that someone can explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this for the `GROUP BY`:

```
GROUP BY  users.name, users.id, `providers`.`id`, providers.name
```

You may have strict `GROUP BY` mode on.  This causes MySQL to follow the ANSI standard and not allow "bare" columns in the `SELECT` in an aggregation query.

Alternatively, you can change the `SELECT` to:

```
SELECT MAX(users.name) AS sellername, users.id AS sellerid,
      `providers`.`id`, MAX(providers.name) AS providername,
```

EDIT:

Oh, on closer inspection, I see the problem.  You have:

```
SUM(COUNT(sales.id)-COUNT(sale_netto.id)) as diff
```

You can't nest aggregation functions.  Presumably, you intend:

```
(COUNT(sales.id)-COUNT(sale_netto.id)) as diff
```

Comment: Thanks but still the same error. Removing the GROUP BY completely still gives the same error for the query.

Comment: The edit which came before the below answer is correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can not aggregate over aggregates: `SUM(COUNT(sales.id)-COUNT(sale_netto.id))`.

Rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT sellername, sellerid, id, providername, brutto, netto, grade, sum(diff), perc
FROM 
(
SELECT users.name AS sellername, users.id AS sellerid, `providers`.`id`, providers.name AS providername, 
COUNT(sales.id) as brutto, COUNT(sale_netto.id) as netto, AVG(sale_quality.grade) as grade, 
COUNT(sales.id)-COUNT(sale_netto.id) as diff, (COUNT(sales.id)/COUNT(sales.id)+COUNT(sale_netto.id))*100 AS perc 
FROM `product_regretrules` 
LEFT JOIN `product_categories` ON `product_categories`.`id` = `product_regretrules`.`product_category_id` 
LEFT JOIN `product_product_category` ON `product_product_category`.`product_category_id` = `product_categories`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `products` ON `products`.`id` = `product_regretrules`.`product_id` 
OR `products`.`id` = `product_product_category.product_id` 
LEFT JOIN `sales` ON `sales`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `sale_netto` ON `sale_netto`.`sale_id` = `sales`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `sales`.`seller_id` 
LEFT JOIN `providers` ON `providers`.`id` = `products`.`provider_id` 
LEFT JOIN `sale_quality` ON `sale_quality`.`sale_id` = `sales`.`id` 
WHERE `sale_netto`.`upload_id` = 725 
AND `sale_netto`.`id` is not null 
AND `sales`.`sell_date` between 2015-12-04 and 2016-08-06 
AND `product_regretrules`.`deleted_at` is null 
GROUP BY `users.id`, `providers`.`id`
) as t
GROUP BY sellername, sellerid, id, providername, brutto, netto, grade, perc;
```